# Removing embedded icon image data from a 'Chrome bookmarks' export

Tags: google-chrome

I regularly export my Chrome bookmarks and store them as a backup to Dropbox (these bookmarks are my 'knowledge-graph,' and are incredibly important to me).

Everything works fine except that the file size is quite huge (a few MBs), and I noticed a potential way to reduce the file size: *the file would be much smaller if I simply removed the embedded icon image information (see image below).*

[image: embedded icon image information]

The part starting with `ICON="data:image/png;base64,` is the embedded icon image information.

Clearly there's no built in way to do this, but I'd love to hear your suggestions on achieving a hack that either:

1. lets me export the bookmarks without the embedded icon image information,

Or:

2. lets me safely remove this information after an export, without too much manual work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome Bookmarks ICON tags

- these ICON tags are basically embedded images. they use up a lot of space. so needed to remove them to reduce the size of my regular bookmark backups in Dropbox.

This worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671925/regex-match-attribute-in-a-html-code

Do a Regex find and replace in Notepad++: Find  `ICON=\"([^"]*)\"`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if the bookmark file's all text, you could just delete the offending lines, and I'm expecting Chrome will open & import them successfully without the non-vital ICON data.

Assuming the data you want to remove always starts with a line `ICON="data:...` and ends with a double-quote (`"`), you could delete it using sed:

```
sed -i '/ICON="/,/"/d' filename
```

`-i` means to edit the file (in-place), and `filename` is the name of the bookmark file.